# How to programmatically control a Java Swing application in a different process?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to write a program to programmatically control a Java Swing application via it is GUI.

The program need to be able to put values on to the text-fields of the application, and hit the "OK" button, just like how a human can do with this application.

I am not familiar with Swing so I don't know where to get started. I looked a few Java Swing GUI testing tools, but they seems all require to launch the Swing application as the part of the tools, while in my use case, it has to be able to control an already running Swing application in a different process.

Answer (score 5):

the java [awt robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class was meant exactly for automating gui interactions. see a nice intoroduction article [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19836.html).

using the robot class you can locate various gui elements by they name/id/position/whatever and interact with them the same way user-generated events will.

about running the ui as part of the tool - of course thats the easiest solution, but you can also inject your code into an already running JVM using the [attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/attach/). you could write a java agent and attach it from another java process (your automation tool) int the running UI application. this is the same mechanism used by debuggers and profilers. there's some example code in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html)

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look at the "Robot" class and related techniques:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to generate/send key commands from your second "debug-test" application, you can use the Java class [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

If you want to change more, you can create an [RMI connection](http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~cs379/DistributedSystems/rmi_tut.html) for booth java application and communicate from one to another. The original app is the server and your debug app is the client.

Because of this you can register the client and send commands to the server. The client can use java classes of the server. the classes are submitted via RMI. So the client can directly contril the frame of the server.

**EDIT:**

You also can use a [Mouse-Click Recorder](http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/). You can start your swing application, start the recorder and click/type whatever you want into your swing application.

Every single click is stored. the next time the swing application is started at the same screen position, you canstart the recorded mouse events and your cursor/keyboard will magically be used to fill you swing app.

Comment: using RMI would require altering the source code for the application being automated to introduce the rmi "back door" :-)